# Excecution does not stop when an exception is throw

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a Solution  with many projects in visual studio 2017, in all except one project (the last that I created it) every execution is stopped when an exception is throw and I can watch every variables and objects, but that does not happen with the last and directly shows me the error in the browser. if I put a breakpoint then it stops execution, but it's not enought.

Comment: Please, clarify what exactly your problem is - add some source code at least.

Comment: my problem is that visual studio does not stop when an exception occurs, when you add a breakpoint the execution stops at both the breakpoint and an exception if the latter happens before, in my case it only stops if I put a breakpoint. It must be some configuration in the project but I did not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You control debugger behavior in VS2017 w.r.t. to exceptions in *Debug* -> *Window* -> *Exception settings*...

One thing to note is that while a number of common exceptions are checked-by-default, `std::exception` is not set to "Break When Thrown" unless you explicitly enable it.